# why do i get use jQuery.uniqueSort warning message in jquery on enabled.sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, deprecated

I am using this js code and on enabled.sortable or disabled.sortable i get this warning message

jQuery.unique is deprecated; use jQuery.uniqueSort

```
        enabled.sortable({
            connectWith: disabled,
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            placeholder: 'ddmultiselect-placeholder',
            items: 'li',
            update: function(event, ui){
                var $values = jQuery.map(enabled.find('li'),function(item){
                    return $(item).data('value');
                });
                field.val($values.join(','));
            }
        }).disableSelection();
        disabled.sortable({
            connectWith: enabled,
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            placeholder: 'ddmultiselect-placeholder',
            items: 'li'
        }).disableSelection();
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You see the warning message because the [$.unique() method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique) is indeed deprecated. If you aren't explicitly using it then I would assume it's being used internally by jQueryUI, or some other library you've included in the page. To remove the message you may need to update these libraries, if they have newer versions available.

Note that this message is not an error, and will not currently cause any functionality to break within your page.

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks for putting me on the right track.  It is Wordpress V 5.7 Beta that is still loading the old libs and also is using deprecated jquery code.

\public\wp-includes\js\jquery\ui